# Python - a function that tests whether the equality a**n + b**n = c**n for n∈{2,3,…,10}

Tags: python

This is not a homework question, I can assure you.

I'm trying to write a function that tests whether the equality `a**n + b**n = c**n`   holds for

n∈{2,3,…,10}.
And if there is a value of n for which the equality holds, the function should return the lowest such value as an `int`. The function should return `False` if the equality does not hold for any value of n in the given range.

e.g.

```
 print(f(3,4,5))
```

outputs:

```
2
```

and

```
print(f(1,2,3))
```

outputs:

```
False
```

I'd love to see the different approaches to such a question. I promise you this is not a homework question. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Woah, 3 vote downs :/

Comment: I'm sure you could've reduced the vote-downs by including at least one attempt at solving this problem yourself?

Comment: @James This question, as well as your previous questions, is inappropriate for this site. You are supposed to show what you have tried, not to post requests for code. Please do not post any more such requests. We do not care whether it's homework for you. It is homework for us.

Comment: I tried with the for loop, but couldn't really get anywhere. I'm very new to programming and was hoping to get some help here

Comment: Okay, from now on I'll post what I've tried. Sorry about that

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty easy due to [Andrew Wiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) who solved **Fermat's last theorem** and proved that for `n > 2` there is no integer solution for `a ** n + b ** n == c ** n`

```
def f(a, b, c):
    return 2 if a * a + b * b == c * c else False
```

Comment: Scrolled down hoping to find an answer like this - was not disappointed :)

Comment: +1 woah ... first I thought you didn't read the question properly(just after you posted the answer) ...came back again to give a reply and .... woah nice ..